# Next js hot reload for local dependency

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js (javascript) for a new project and have included a fork of a dependency locally within the project by modifying the "package" field in the package.json file as follows:

```
"package": "file:./path/to/the/package"
```

This works, but now I'm trying to enable hot reloading for this dependency by changing the "package" field to:

```
"package": "link:./path/to/the/package"
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Error: require() of ES Module
Instead change the require of index.js in .../.next/server/pages/page.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Is there a way to fix this error and enable hot reloading for local dependencies in Next.js, or is there another approach I can take to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

NextJS gives you the ability to configure webpack from within the `next.config.js` file.

I'm loading in the `webpack-watch-files-plugin` and then configuring it to watch my local dependencies.

I also have to configure polling for reasons that are not entirely clear to me, but it works.

You'll have to install the [webpack-watch-files-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin) first.
If you're using npm, you can just use this command: `npm i --save-dev webpack-watch-files-plugin`

Heres the config I use:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const WatchExternalFilesPlugin = require("webpack-watch-files-plugin").default;
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (
    config,
    { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }
  ) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };
    config.plugins.push(
      //change 'tsx' and 'ts' to 'jsx' and 'js' if you're not using typescript
      new WatchExternalFilesPlugin({
        files: ["{directory containing packages}/**/*.tsx", "{directory containing packages}/**/*.ts"],
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {},
  //not needed if you're not using typescript
  transpilePackages: ["{packagename as defined in package.json}"]
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My dependency looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "{package name}": "{package path}"
},
```

I'm using my package like so:

```js
import { ... } from "{package name}";
```